# Openshift autoscalling offline application

Tags: scaling, openshift, autoscaling

I'd like to use OpenShift to host an application that will consume some data from queue and put it to database. So it won't receive http requests. Is there a way to automatically scale it up? (To minimize the time data spends in queue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are going to use a paid plan, this application would get idled after 48 hours.  You can use the rhc command to scaled your application up and down manually

Comment: I'm going to deploy it on OpenShift Origin, but information that I can do it only manually is really helpful. Haven't you thought about some other metrics for scaling application (e.g. resources usage)?